# Reset Parameters in Report Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportparameter

I have a report that lists people and flag.

```
idPerson | nmPerson | Flag
01       | Carl     | 0
02       | Eva      | 1
03       | Jhon     | 1
```

**I want to update the flag when I click on the flag field**. To do this, I created a **dataset that calls a procedure to update the flag on table** passing the parameter @idPerson. The parameter @idPerson allows null value. In the **action of the flag field I put to go to the same report**, with @idPerson as parameter.

The problem is that it only works when I click on different lines because the parameter updates with a new value, **if I click on the same line, the report does not execute the procedure**.

I think I have to reset the parameter but I do not know how I do it.

*How I do to reset the parameter value to default, or another way to update the flag on table without go to another report?*